# Pointing Domain at Webmin Webserver

Tags: dns, portforwarding, webmin, virtualmin

I am at the point where I can successfully access my webmin login from my ip address from anywhere, and that when i go to http://host.inputgeo.com it gives me the ubuntu deafult page, but doing http or https://host.inputgeo.com:10000 which should take me to login does not work. I just want to be able to access the login from my domain.

Thanks, George.

Comment: I think you switch to Hestia CP, much better tho

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same trouble with you. Just point and it should work. If you using CloudFlare as DNS, remember to turn off proxy. Just DNS.